# Flutter: any widget invisible when using stack in google map

Tags: flutter, dart, google-maps

I have weird error, whatever widget I'm made in stack google map are invisible. the widget still there and can interact. for example I made button it can clicked and do the action. but its not visible. my flutter version is 3.3.9, google_map_flutter 2.2.2.

[This is my map when load to created it's show my button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3z48T.png)

[this is my map when I created](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wHeGq.png)

this my widget tree

```
Stack(
children: <Widget>[

  Container(
    child: Obx(
          () => GoogleMap(
        onTap: (position) {
          _customInfoWindowController.hideInfoWindow!();
        },
        onCameraMove: (position) {
          _customInfoWindowController.onCameraMove!();
        },
        onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
          _customInfoWindowController.googleMapController =
              controller;
          newGoogleMapController = controller;
          updateCameraPosition(
              -8.466803395691676, 115.2199474850532, false);
        },
        zoomGesturesEnabled: false,
        myLocationEnabled: true,
        mapToolbarEnabled: true,
        zoomControlsEnabled: false,
        tiltGesturesEnabled: false,
        markers: Set<Marker>.of(markers.value),
        initialCameraPosition: _initialCameraPosition,
      ),
    ),
  ),


  Container(
    child: WidgetButton.btnStyle2(
        name: 'Update Camera Maps',
        action: () {
          updateCameraPosition(
              -8.371809235984502, 114.93838766787734, true);
        }),
  ),
  CustomInfoWindow(
    controller: _customInfoWindowController,
    height: 500,
    width: 500,
    offset: 50,
  ),
  ],
);
```

This is my flutter doctor -v

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.3.9, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22621.900], locale en-ID)
    • Flutter version 3.3.9 on channel stable at C:\android\flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision b8f7f1f986 (3 weeks ago), 2022-11-23 06:43:51 +0900
    • Engine revision 8f2221fbef
    • Dart version 2.18.5
    • DevTools version 2.15.0

Checking Android licenses is taking an unexpectedly long time...[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Platform android-33, build-tools 30.0.3
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.13+0-b1751.21-8125866)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

[√] Android Studio (version 2021.3)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.13+0-b1751.21-8125866)

[√] VS Code (version 1.73.1)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.54.0
```

Maybe I missing a small step, I have try google it too but no solution. it's seem error with flutter 3. my previous project run normal in stack with flutter 2. even floating action button not visible.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to put a Container on top of every widget like this?

```
Stack(
children: <Widget>[

  Container(
    child: Obx(
          () => GoogleMap(
        onTap: (position) {
          _customInfoWindowController.hideInfoWindow!();
        },
        onCameraMove: (position) {
          _customInfoWindowController.onCameraMove!();
        },
        onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
          _customInfoWindowController.googleMapController =
              controller;
          newGoogleMapController = controller;
          updateCameraPosition(
              -8.466803395691676, 115.2199474850532, false);
        },
        zoomGesturesEnabled: false,
        myLocationEnabled: true,
        mapToolbarEnabled: true,
        zoomControlsEnabled: false,
        tiltGesturesEnabled: false,
        markers: Set<Marker>.of(markers.value),
        initialCameraPosition: _initialCameraPosition,
      ),
    ),
  ),
  CustomInfoWindow(
    controller: _customInfoWindowController,
    height: 500,
    width: 500,
    offset: 50,
  ),
   Container(
    child: WidgetButton.btnStyle2(
        name: 'Update Camera Maps',
        action: () {
          updateCameraPosition(
              -8.371809235984502, 114.93838766787734, true);
        }),
  ),
  ],
);
```

Comment: No, i just want try it in this widget hope something diferent happen when i change height.